# PHP scripts are returning 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, centos, cgi

I get 500 error for PHP scripts, but HTML files are served without a problem.

Here are my configs:

httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/data/www/example.com
    ServerAdmin example@mail.com
    AddDefaultCharset off
    SuexecUserGroup root root
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    ScriptAlias /php-bin/ /var/www/php-bin-isp-php56/example/
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php-bin/php
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/example/data/www/example.com/cgi-bin/
    ServerAlias www.en.tour.mosmetro.ru
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory /var/www/example/data/www/example.com>
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
```

error log

```
[Sat Jul 20 00:13:42.939412 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 6532] [client 127.0.0.1:39994] End of script output before headers: php
```

Comment: I would check file permissions for the php script in question.

Comment: Include the PHP file that you are requesting.  It's a good idea to try hitting a simple test PHP file, e.g. one that only contains `<?php phpinfo();` -- if the test file works, then you know the problem is with your script, not with PHP itself.

Comment: everywhere 777 permissions. script `<?php phpinfo();` throws the same error.